# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, nsjsonserialization

i am trying to use a json into another json but getting this error " Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map'"

i am using jsonserializable
this is my data file i want to use it in product file

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Data {
  final String name;
  final String price;

  Data(this.name, this.price);

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DataToJson(this);
}
```

productmodel file

```
import 'package:doorstep/domain/model/data.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'product-model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ProductModel {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String image;
  final bool isLast;
  final bool icon;
  final List<Data> data;

  ProductModel(
      this.id, this.title, this.image, this.isLast, this.icon, this.data);

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProductModelToJson(this);
}
```

getting error in the productmodel file : " Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map'"